# ImportError: cannot import name 'LEMMA_INDEX' from 'spacy.lang.en'

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

I'm trying to make a lemmatizer in spaCy, however when I run the code I have, this error keeps popping up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word_pract.py", line 46, in <module>
    from spacy.lang.en import LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES
ImportError: cannot import name 'LEMMA_INDEX' from 'spacy.lang.en'
```

This is the code,

```
import spacy
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
from spacy.lang.en import LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES)
lemmas = lemmatizer(u'ducks', u'NOUN')
print(lemmas)
```

I have spaCy up to date, and am on python 3.7.4 in a conda environment. I also download en_core_web_sm, so I don't know why its wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a change from v2.1 to v2.2 to move the large lookup tables out of the main library. The lemmatizer data is now stored in the separate package `spacy-lookups-data` and the `Lemmatizer` is initialized with a `Lookups` object instead of the individual variables. See the second section here about initializing lemmatizers: https://spacy.io/usage/v2-2#migrating

If you install the package `spacy-lookups-data`, you can access the default English lemmatizer like this:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
lemmatizer = English.Defaults.create_lemmatizer()
```

It automatically loads the data from `spacy-lookups-data` if it's available. If it's not available, the lemmas will be the same as the tokens from the text.

If you use an English model like `en_core_web_sm`, the lookup tables are included with the model, so you don't need the additional package `spacy-lookups-data`:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
lemmatizer = nlp.Defaults.create_lemmatizer()
```